# Firebase Functions - Get data from the main collection when a document is created in a sub collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is how my firestore db looks like

- Feed (main collection)

  - Feed 1 (documents under main collection)
  - Feed 2

    - comments (sub-collection)

      - comment 1 (document in sub-collection)
      - comment 2

I'm trying to access the information in the document under main-collection when a new comment is added using firebase function. Is there a way to access that information ?

my current code, im only able to access the commentDoc data

```
exports.newComment=functions.firestore.document('Feed/{FeedDoc}/comments/{commentDoc}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
const commentData = snap.data()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows, using the `parent` methods of a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#parent) and of a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#parent):

```
exports.newComment=functions.firestore.document('Feed/{FeedDoc}/comments/{commentDoc}')
 .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {   // Note the async keyword
    const commentData = snap.data();

    const feedDocRef = snap.ref.parent.parent;
    const feedSnap = await feedDocRef.get();
    // ...
});
```

---

Or you can do as follows, using [`context.params`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#params):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.newComment=functions.firestore.document('Feed/{FeedDoc}/comments/{commentDoc}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
   const commentData = snap.data();

   const feedDocId = context.params.FeedDoc;
   const feedSnap = await admin.firestore().doc(`Feed/${FeedDocId}`).get();
   // ...
});
```